# Get karate parameter inside ExecutionHook Implementation class

Tags: karate

I have the below *karate-config.js* file where I am reading the *globalJson* file.

```js
function(){
  
    var globalJsonObj = '';
    var config = {
        globalJsonObj : '',
    };
    config.globalJsonObj = read('classpath:global-config.json');
    
    return config;
}
```

Now I have implemented `ExecutionHook` class. In the `afterFeature` method I want to access `lobalJsonObj`.

Is there a way in which I can access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend doing so much with the ExecutionHook - please find an alternative if possible, because the API may change in the future. This is why it is not in the official documentation and readme. If you are needing so much of control, contribute code to the main framework or suggest changes instead.

That said, you can try `ScenarioContext.eval("globalJsonObj").getValue()` - if you still have questions, please read the source code.